# Making a clean looking Doxygen ALIAS with HTML

Tags: html, alias, doxygen

I have a working Doxygen ALIAS code using HTML (via @htmlonly), that in order to display a youtube video, allows me to simply write in the (".markdown")-file:

Youtube Link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**CODE**
```

With ALIAS:

```
@youtube{**CODE**}
```

Without ALIAS:

```
@htmlonly

<div align="center">
<iframe
    title="my title" width="560" height="349"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/**CODE**?rel=0&loop=1"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen align="middle">
</iframe>
</div>

@endhtmlonly
```

By adding the following ALIAS to the Doxyfile:

```
ALIASES               += youtube{1}="@htmlonly<div align='center'><iframe title='my title' width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\1?rel=0&loop=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen align='middle'></iframe></div>@endhtmlonly"
```

My problem is that the macro as you can see from above is **HUGE** and looks really **CONFUSING**!

**Questions**:

1. Is there a way to make it look clean?
2. What should I do with bigger HTML raw codes?
3. Should I be using any other Doxygen alternative to the ALIAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

Instead of:

```
ALIASES               += youtube{1}="@htmlonly<div align='center'><iframe title='my title' width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\1?rel=0&loop=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen align='middle'></iframe></div>@endhtmlonly"
```

I can use:

@youtube{link}, with:

```
ALIASES+=addyoutube{1}="@htmlonly</p><div class='addYoutube'>\1</div>@endhtmlonly"
ALIASES+=youtube{1}="@addyoutube{\1} @htmlinclude add_youtube.html"

EXAMPLE_PATH          += @CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@/add_youtube.html
```

And add the following javascript code in a file in the current directory, add_youtube.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $getDiv = $('div.addYoutube').last();

var filmId = $getDiv.html()
filmId = filmId.replace("https://","")
filmId = filmId.replace("www.","")
filmId = filmId.replace("youtube.com/watch?v=","")

document.write("<div align='center'><iframe title='my title' width='560' height='349' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+filmId+"?rel=0&loop=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen align='middle'> </iframe> </div>");
$getDiv.remove()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit to late for a party, but in Doxygen 1.8.12 it is possible to create some combination of doxygen tags `@brief` and HTML elements. 
When you defining attributes for HTML elements it is possible to use apostrophes `class='someClass'` or you can also use quote sign with a backslash `class=\"someClass\"`. 
To indent the html use the string concantenation with a backslash sign `\`.

```
ALIASES +=               "briefWithImage{3} = @brief \
                            @htmlonly \
                                <span><img class='imgBriefImage' src='\1' alt='\1'></span> \
                                </span><span class='spanBriefText'>\2(<b>\3</b>)</span> \
                            @endhtmlonly"
```

I'm not sure about alternatives to aliases. One way is to define your custom HTML header for each page and when page is loaded - replace your own placeholders using custom JS functions.

Comment: Why advising something about version 1.8.12 (whilst version 1.8.15 is out). Note also the changes in the ALIAS in respect to the return, i.e. use now `^^`